grafana alerting memory > 80 %
In my grafana dahsboard I use node-eporter and prometheus as the data source to scrape server metrics:
The dashboard offers several queries by default, such as these to calculate the total amount of memory averaged over time:
100 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance="$node",job="$job"}[$__rate_interval]) * 100) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$node",job="$job"}[$__rate_interval]))

I would like to translate the above query into an alert rule in grafana which will fire whenever the RAM usage is above 80%. Any easy way to do this ?
